# Integrating jni and .so files to Android Project

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have an Android Project in Eclipse 4.5. I have a jni folder with .c and .h files. I also have .so file which needs to be added to lib folder. But I dont know how to add these to my Android Project and make my Project running. Any kind of assistance would help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer on my own -

Add android ndk tools to a location where your android sdk is present.

Now in your eclipse project, create a jni folder with all your .c and .h files and also your Android.mk file.

Now in your eclipse, goto Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration. For location, press "Browse File System" and choose the "ndk-build" location(which you have put in android sdk folder) For Working Directory, press "Browse Workspace" and choose your eclipse project and your jni folder. For example like this - ${workspace_loc:/yourproject/jni}

Press Apply and then press Run. You have your .so in libs folder of your eclipse project.